# Maven unable to resolve Proguard 4.9 dependencies from local Nexus setup

Tags: maven, dependencies, proguard, dependency-management

I have a problem on maven dependencies when it tries to resolve dependencies that is not configured in the project level, but is configured on the plugin level. It always looks from maven central and won't check in our internal repo.

Below is the pom configuration. Problem is that it will always look for proguard version 4.2 in the central even if we have configured it as proguard 4.9 and supposed to be fethcing the one in our internal nexus:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>com.pyx4me</groupId>
            <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals><goal>proguard</goal></goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <proguardVersion>4.9</proguardVersion>
                <obfuscate>true</obfuscate>
                <proguardInclude>conf/proguard_gsma-sms-validator.conf</proguardInclude>
                <includeDependency>false</includeDependency>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>net.sf.proguard</groupId>
                    <artifactId>proguard</artifactId>
                    <version>4.9</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

Im not sure if this is Maven problem or pyx4me problem or proguard. But im guessing it's a problem with Maven.

This can only be resolved if we do a maven install:install-file to proguard version 4.9. But we want maven to settle dependencies by fetching the one from our internal Nexus.

Please advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The plugin com.pyx4me:proguard-maven-plugin:2.0.4 depends on net.sf.proguard:**proguard**:4.3, which was initiated and maintained by the developers of Pyx4me.

However, recent versions of ProGuard are available as net.sf.proguard:**proguard-base**:4.2+ and related modules, as [initiated by Marcel Patzlaff](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/OSSRH-913) and currently maintained by myself.

You can find a list of all of them at [maven.org](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3a%22net.sf.proguard%22). Note the latest version numbers. ProGuard itself should still be compatible, so you can try replacing the dependency by excluding the former and adding the latter.

Comment: I tried, however its still not working. it still looks for the 4.3 :(

Comment: You must use Maven's <exclusion> tags to suppress the dependency on 4.3.